# In jQuery Mobile, can you link to another local page and use a hash?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova, hashtag

If I'm on a page, such as `index.html`, can I link to `app.html#myID`? Right now, the link will only work if I use `app.html` and `rel="external"`

Works:

```
<li id="ten"><a href="app.html" rel="external">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<li id="ten"><a href="app.html#ten-ten">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

This is done locally through Chrome using file:// and will be compiled into PhoneGap and displayed as an app.

Answer (score 1):

there is millions of questions about this topic just in stackoverflow alone. JQM doesn't have the option of loading externals pages with subpages. it only load the first div with data-role="page".

So while we wait for this option to be available in JQM you should split you external multipage to several pages